# xml tag value - Upper case change into camel case

Tags: regex, notepad++

Seeking help to convert the case of tag values.

```
    <folder><title>TestGrp01</title>
        <program><title>V-Test Name 01</title><rulename>AVL_KMPL_AQS_SW_YRT</rulename></program>
        <program><title>V-Test Name 02</title><rulename>KML_RTWE_WE_SQ</rulename></program>
    </folder>
    <folder><title>TestGrp02</title>
        <program><title>V-Test Name 11</title><rulename>DER_ADEF_GT_IK_KIU</rulename></program>
        <program><title>V-Test Name 12</title><rulename>SDFDF_WE_OK</rulename></program>
    </folder>
```

I want to convert the values inside the rulename tag into camel case as below.

AVL_KMPL_AQS_SW_YRT --> Avl_Kmpl_Aqs_Sw_Yrt

KML_RTWE_WE_SQ --> Kml_Rtwe_We_Sq

DER_ADEF_GT_IK_KIU --> Der_Adef_Gt_Ik_Kiu

SDFDF_WE_OK --> Sdfdf_We_Ok

So the final output to be as follows.

```
    <folder><title>TestGrp01</title>
        <program><title>V-Test Name 01</title><rulename>Avl_Kmpl_Aqs_Sw_Yrt</rulename></program>
        <program><title>V-Test Name 02</title><rulename>Kml_Rtwe_We_Sq</rulename></program>
    </folder>
    <folder><title>TestGrp02</title>
        <program><title>V-Test Name 11</title><rulename>Der_Adef_Gt_Ik_Kiu</rulename></program>
        <program><title>V-Test Name 12</title><rulename>Sdfdf_We_Ok</rulename></program>
    </folder>
```

Comment: While it is possible if `<rulename>` tag cannot have children, why not parse it with XML parser inside code? You might not even need a regex then.

Comment: The code is copy righted and cannot be changed and need to pass the values in camel case hence the request is made here

Comment: Did you see [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/115432/converting-text-to-title-case-in-notepad)? I expect you can use this to come to a desired result.

Comment: I referred it before posting this question. the TextFX helps but I need to select the values manually and choose Proper Case. Other answers doesn't match.

Comment: @Sathish  do you want this to be done with excel formulas??

Comment: Thanks Guys, I have done this through excel.